# Open new Fragment (Tab) on Button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-button, android-tabs

I am using `ViewPager` with `ActionBar` Tabs and I easily can swipe between tabs(`fragment`s), and I also can open another tab `onClick` of that tab.

But, I want to on button click from one tab to open another tab(fragment).

Take a look on the picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After creating your Tab, store the tab in a variable so that it is accessable in your Buttons `onClick` method. Then call the [ActionBar.Tab.select()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html#select%28%29) method inside your `onClick` method of your button.

Use something like this: (I could not check everything, but it should give you the idea)

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
final Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
Button button = new Button(getActivity());
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        tab.select();   
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zookey: I added some code. If you would add some code of your Tab initialisation this would also be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved this problem:

```
private ActionBar actionBar;
```

Then I put this in onCreate()

```
actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
```

And then I created button on click listener like this:

```
btnLocationReviews.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(3);


            }
```